# Insert items with rest into a read only list?

Tags: 2013, list, rest, item, read-only

So i have this problem. I want my list to be read only for everyone (maybe not administrators). So far i can just set some permissions and work is done. But then i want to be able to upload items using the Rest Services. I know how to upload items it's not a problem. But I want to be able to upload them to a read only list... Is this even possible?

I thought about creating a workflow that would change the item permissions once an item is created and set it to read only. But then it means that you can create items in the list from sharepoint so the list isn't read only. Items once created from rest would, i assume, start the workflow and set the item permission level. But then you would also be able to create items directly from sharepoint (which i don't want).

So far i can't think of a solution.

I've seen people changing list permissions between read only and edit with rest but that's just so risky it's not a viable solution for me.

**Do you have any ideas how this could be achieved?**

I know that i could do like some crazy look ups but with 20+ columns it means you would have 20+ look ups so threshold would block it and infopath forms would stop working so that wouldn't work neither.

Comment: Only administrators will be adding items to the list  right?

Comment: @Unnie That the problem. I have an external app using Rest Service. You can upload items to lists with this app. So Users that use this app log into Sharepoint (via the app) with their own logins. Therefore they have to be able to create items in a read only list for them. I know it's nonsens but i somehow have to achieve this.

Comment: Use a drop off list and a workflow with elevated permissions to create the item in the read only list and delete the item from the dropoff list

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman What do you mean? I've searched on the internet and i don't understand what's a drop off list. And if i'm right elevating permissions for simple users is generally a bad thing, isn't it? Anyway. could you post an example as an answer so i can test it?

Comment: A dropoff list is a second list where users DO have write access, they "drop" the content, your workflow picks it up and delivers it to the read-onbly list

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman So they will be able to create items on sharepoint. I'm trying to achieve creating items only via my rest calls. Sharepoint need to be read only for normal users.

Comment: Impossible, if you don't have a key you can't get into the house. So like with snail mail you create a small place where someone can drop information in the house. The workflow then picks up the data and delivers it into the house

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yeah ok. I'll speak with my project manager then cause i just got a headache thinking about every possibilities. I thought about this mirroring list stuff but yeah once again you still will be able to create items on sharepoint. And even if you hide the base list you still will be able to access it if you know the url. Thanks for participating Danny, appreciate it.